# Django queryset sin modelos

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, pandas

Necesito hacer consultas a la base de datos (`postgresql`) pero las tablas que quiero consultar fueron creadas por `pandas`por lo que no tengo un modelo al cual referirme, como hago para hacer consultas sin modelos ?

Comment: No puedes usar el ORM sin modelos, pero lo que puedes hacer es inspeccionar las tablas y que django genere los modelos: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: No tenia conocimiento de ese comando `inspectdb` y estoy siguiendo lo que me indica la pagina, lo que no entiendo es que hago luego con el `models.py` generado, pues me crea modelos de tablas que ya tenia en modelos en otras aplicaciones (no se si me di a entender con esa ultima parte) igual muchas gracias por el link